# TCP socket data getting scrambled

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a Multi threaded TCP socket listener program. I do a blocked read for data of a particular no of bytes(128 bytes and 4xmultiples),so my packet sizes are 128 bytes,256 bytes,384 bytes and 512 bytes.

I am having problem because sometimes data is getting messed in the socket. For eg:

Supposed to read:

```
<header><data payload(padded with zeros to compensate size)><footer>
```

ex-- **ABCDddddddddd0000000000WXYZ**

What i read sometimes:

ex-- **ABCDdd00000000000000000dddddd00**

and then the next packet looks like

**00000WXYZABCDddddd00000000000000000**

so i close the socket and we have defined the protocol to send back 2 or 3 old packets to avoid the loss.

my questions are

***1. why does the data get scrambled/messed?***

***2. can it be avoided by any means?***

here is my code for read data.

```
in = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
while (m_bRunThread) {
    // read incoming stream
    in.readFully(rec_data_in_byte, 0, 128); //blocks until 128 bytes are read from the socket
    {
        //converting the read byte array into string
        //finding out the size from a particular position,helps determine if any further reads are required or not.
        //if the size is a multiple of 128 and the size is a multiple higher than 1 then more reads are required.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(SIZE) % 128 == 0) && ((SIZE / 128) > 1)) {
            for(int z = 1;z < lenSIZE;z++) {
                in.readFully(rec_data_in_byte1, 0, 128);//changed from in.read(rec_data_in_byte1, 0, 128); as per suggestions
            }
            //extracting the data,validating and processing it
        }
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Implemented ***Peters*** fix but the problem still persists. data is getting scrambled.
adding a few lines of extra code where the byte array is converted into a string.

```
byte[] REC_data=new byte[1024];
System.arraycopy(rec_data_in_byte1, 0, REC_data, 128*z, 128);
rec_data_string=MyClass2.getData(REC_data,0,Integer.parseInt(SIZE)-1,Integer.parseInt(SIZE));
```

the getdata() method is below:

```
String msg = "";//the return String
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < datasize; i++) {
        if (i >= startindex) {
            if (count <= lengthofpacket) {
                msg += String.valueOf((char) (bytedata[i]));
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return msg;
```

can any of this be the reason for the scramble?

**P.S**-the scramble is happening the same way as it was happening before.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Your edit invalidated the answer given by Peter Lawrey. If you followed the advice of Peter, then either ask a new question, or update your question to **add** the new things you tried and what you saw. Note that you should really also include the code used to write the data. The problem could just as well be there.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel-thanks for the advice. will do that from now on. new to the world of stackoverflow..

Comment: After all the updates and rollbacks you still have a `read()` method whose return value you are not using. You need to use `readFully()` everywhere, or appropriate code that doesn't assume that `read()` filled the buffer. TCP is a byte stream and isn't obliged to deliver you more than one byte at a time.

Comment: @EJP- i am using read fully every where,i changed that here and still not getting. Also i am a follower of you and your posts and i know that **TCP is a stream protocol. There are no packets, just a single stream of data.**

Comment: I am commenting on the code you posted. `in.read(rec_data_in_byte1, 0, 128);` is still there. I can't see into your computer. Neither can anybody else.

Comment: @EJP-i changed it but  Mark Rotteveel rolled back my edit saying ' it invalidated the answer given by Peter Lawrey'. i will change it now.

Comment: And why are you parsing what appears to be a constant into an integer?

Comment: @EJP- the variable `SIZE` is a string variable and a constant value but changes from packet to packet as per protocol and is extracted from a string from a particular position. the method and calculations take an integer value so passing it as an integer.

Comment: 'Constant value but changes from packet to packet' is a contradiction in terms. Please try to make sense.

Comment: constant as in its either 128,256,384 or 512. changing with each incoming packet. the client is programed to create packets of either of the 4 sizes only according to data availability. if less data is there at send time the size can be 128 bytes but if more data is there the size can be 512 bytes too.

Comment: @EJP- any suggestions?

Comment: Why is this question tagged "multithreading"?  You say that the code example comes from a multi-threaded program, but your question does not ask anything about threads, and your example code does not create any threads or perform any synchronization of threads or communication between threads.

Comment: @james large- sorry to have dissapointed you. the reference was made so as people who work and code on a similar platform as me can be reached out to get help if they have ever encountered any such similar problem and solved it.

Comment: OK, so "Java" is appropriate because you are looking for people who know Java and its libraries; "sockets" is appropriate (assuming that your variable `conn` is a `java.net.Socket`.)  "Tcp" is OK:  Your question is not specifically _about_ the TCP protocol, but it does relate to the behavior of a TCP socket.  The only tag that really does not belong here is "multithreading" since you ask nothing about threads, give no examples of thread-related code, nor any hint that multi-threading could be related to your problem.

Comment: @james large-ok fine..will keep that in mind the next time i post..now instead of talking about tags..can we talk about a solution to the problem i have..please share your views and solutions if you have any.

Comment: @JayeshTripathi ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
int lengthActuallyRead = in.read(rec_data_in_byte1, 0, 128);
```

You need to check the length read.  Otherwise it might read 1 byte, or anything up to 128 in this case.  Note, any bytes after what was actually read are untouched so they might be `0` or they could be garbage left from a previous message.

If you expect 128 bytes you can use `readFully` as you did previously

```
in.readFully(rec_data_in_byte, 0, 128);
```

Note: If the amount remaining is less than 128 you might want to do this.

```
int remaining = size - sizeReadSoFar;
int length = in.read(rec_data_in_byte1, 0, remaining);
```

This prevents you reading part of the next message while you are still reading the old one.

Comment: my protocol is designed on the client side to send packets 128 bytes only and multiples upto 4, so the data read will be always be 128 and multiples of it. also editing the code now the **read** is a **readfully** now,so it serves the purpose.

Comment: but still my question remains can the data get scrambled/messed?

Comment: @JayeshTripathi the data is not corrupted on the wire, though it can get corrupted if you don't read it correctly.

Comment: so as per my edit on the code and your suggestion it should solve the problem now. right?

Comment: @JayeshTripathi yes. You might want to use a BufferedInputStream to reduce the number of actual reads to the OS.

Comment: thanks for the input,implemented it on my code. also how to use BufferedInputStream in my case. curious to know how it would help. any sample code or example to figure it out....

Comment: @JayeshTripathi You wrap the `in` once and use that instead.

Comment: @PeterLawrey- how do i do that?? (it might be a lame question but help)

Comment: @JayeshTripathi in your code you have used DataInputStream as wrapper already, so you do exactly the same thing but with BufferedInputStream as well. `in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));`

Comment: @PeterLawrey-cheked it over night..dosen't seem to be helping..still data is getting scrambled.

Comment: @JayeshTripathi in that case, I would look at how the data is being written.